# Pandas DataFrame update from another dataframe only if a column does not have a value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to update a dataframe using the values in another dataframe but I would like the update to happen only if a particular column does not have a value.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

dr = pd.bdate_range(periods=3, end=datetime.now().date())

df1 = pd.DataFrame([1, 2], columns=['myid'])
for d in dr:                                                                                                                                   
    df1[d.to_pydatetime()] = pd.np.nan
df1.loc[df1['myid'] == 1, dr[2]] = 4.0
df1 = df1.set_index('myid')


df1
      2019-11-13 00:00:00  2019-11-14 00:00:00  2019-11-15 00:00:00
myid                                                               
1                     NaN                  NaN                  4.0
2                     NaN                  NaN                  NaN

df2 = pd.DataFrame([1, 2], columns=['myid'])
for d in dr:                                                                                                                                   
    df2[d.to_pydatetime()] = pd.np.nan
df2.loc[df2['myid'] == 2, dr[2]] = 4.0
df2.loc[df2['myid'] == 1, dr[0]] = 6.0
df2 = df2.set_index('myid')

df2
      2019-11-13 00:00:00  2019-11-14 00:00:00  2019-11-15 00:00:00
myid                                                               
1                     6.0                  NaN                  NaN
2                     NaN                  NaN                  4.0
```

I would like to update df1 with values in df2 if df1 does not have a value for `dr[2] (current date)`

So in the above example only the second row in df1 should get updated.

I tried `update` as follows but not sure how to filter based on whether the column has a value or not

```
df1.update(df2, overwrite=False)
```

I did look at `filter_func` that update takes but again unable to make this work with it. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

EDIT:

Expected output:

Row 1 should not be touched because it already has a value in column `2019-11-15 00:00:00`

```
df1
      2019-11-13 00:00:00  2019-11-14 00:00:00  2019-11-15 00:00:00
myid                                                               
1                     NaN                  NaN                  4.0
2                     NaN                  NaN                  4.0
```

Comment: So any non-null value in a row disqualifies that entire row for updating?

Comment: @ALollz non-null value in the column `2019-11-15 00:00:00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: This seems to be an obvious use for the `filter_func` argument. Update only rows where all columns of `df1` are null:

```
df1.update(df2, filter_func=lambda df: df1.isnull().all(1))
#      2019-11-13 00:00:00  2019-11-14 00:00:00  2019-11-15 00:00:00
#myid                                                               
#1                     NaN                  NaN                  4.0
#2                     NaN                  NaN                  4.0
```

---

Old answer, more hands-on:

You can separate which rows to update, update only those rows then combine. `update` operates inplace so we need to split things out.

```
m = df1.notnull().any(1)

# These get updated
u = df1[~m].copy()
u.update(df2)

df1 = pd.concat([df1[m], u])
#      2019-11-13 00:00:00  2019-11-14 00:00:00  2019-11-15 00:00:00
#myid                                                               
#1                     NaN                  NaN                  4.0
#2                     NaN                  NaN                  4.0
```

---

Alternatively, you could use `combine_first`, then mask rows that shouldn't have been updated and reset them back to the original values in `df1`

```
df1.combine_first(df2).mask(df1.notnull().any(1)).fillna(df1)
```

Comment: Thank you this works well. Any chance this can be done using `filter_func`?

Comment: See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html

```
filter_func : callable(1d-array) -> bool 1d-array, optional
Can choose to replace values other than NA. Return True for values that should be updated.
```

Comment: @kTest yes you're right, I wasn't aware of that argument. It's probably the simplest way to do this, I updated the solution.